# PHP fileinfo and MimeType.php

Tags: file-uploads, files

I get this error after upgrading to EE 2.10.1

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function EllisLab\ExpressionEngine\Library\Mime\finfo_open() in
>   /home/foo/bar/EllisLab/ExpressionEngine/Library/Mime/MimeType.php on
>   line 117

I can't upload files through the CP or synchronise in file manager.

I've tried adding fileinfo.so to extension in php.ini as suggsted here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3579072/php-fileinfo-is-undefined-function but it didn't do anything, just got the same error message.

Answer (score 4):

EllisLab addresses this issue on a [blog post](https://ellislab.com/blog/entry/fileinfo-in-2-10-0). Part of it:

> If you encounter problems with uploading files check the following:
>
> 1. Login to your CP and go to Tools, then Utilities, then PHP Info. If you see --disable-fileinfo on that page (I recommend using your browser’s search function) then you will need to contact your host and have them provide a version of PHP with fileinfo not disabled (i.e. enabled).
> 2. Check your system/expressionengine/config/mimes.php file. If it does not contain $whitelist = array around line 31 you will need to upload a fresh copy.

There's more useful info there.

Comment: Your right about --disable-fileinfo showing up under 'Configure Command'. I've already added extension = "fileinfo.so" in my php.ini so not sure why still showing as disabled?

Comment: Did you restarted PHP? I'm just trying to guess now.

Comment: yes, restarted Apache and a graceful server reboot. I've opened a ticket with the hosting company, maybe they can help out.

Comment: Had the same issue, my host company installed fileinfo php module (using easyapache) and that fixed the issue. davor

Comment: I'm having the same issue, but fileinfo is enabled and $whitelist is in the mimes.php

Comment: FYI, fileinfo doesn't work properly out of the box on Dreamhost servers, there's more info here: http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/32870/unresolved-error-with-ee-2-10-1-and-mimetype-php

Comment: Anyone know of an alternative work around if hosts cant help with fileinfo?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this installing php7.0-gd.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt-get update
```

Next, install the desired version:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-gd
# or
sudo apt-get install php7.1-gd
# or
sudo apt-get install php7.2-gd
```