# Unresolved error with EE 2.10.1 and MimeType.php

Tags: file-uploads, error

I'm getting the same error as [this question](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/31370/php-fileinfo-and-mimetype-php):

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function
>   EllisLab\ExpressionEngine\Library\Mime\finfo_open() in
>   /home/foo/bar/EllisLab/ExpressionEngine/Library/Mime/MimeType.php on
>   line 117

There are two suggestions offered (originally from an Ellis blog post):

> 1. Login to your CP and go to Tools, then Utilities, then PHP Info. If you see --disable-fileinfo on that page (I recommend using your
>      browser’s search function) then you will need to contact your host and
>      have them provide a version of PHP with fileinfo not disabled (i.e.
>      enabled).
> 2. Check your system/expressionengine/config/mimes.php file. If it does not contain $whitelist = array around line 31 you will need to
>      upload a fresh copy.

... but I've checked both of those, and I'm still getting the same error. Any other suggestions?

I'm in a fresh install of EE 2.10.1, on a Dreamhost server running PHP 5.6.10.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just encountered this, and found that I had to follow the instructions in [this Dreamhost wiki entry](http://wiki.dreamhost.com/Fileinfo) to *truly* enable `fileinfo` functions. (The default "shared" `fileinfo` support didn't cut it.)